# In Drupal, how to output content type markup only (no page markup) without using .tpl files

Tags: drupal, content-management-system

Using D7.
I have several instances where I need to output just the content types markup, none of the pages markup(i.e. popup content). Currently I create several tpl files (for each rendering layer) for each content type stripping out all surrounding html, these tpls only have a single output line. 
This extremely inefficient and cumbersome. I know there must be an easier way to handle doing this in the template.php file I just cant seem to find the answer.
Any help appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did this with the following trick

**1) edit your template.php**

```
 function mytheme_preprocess_page(&$variables, $hook) {
   if (isset($_GET['modal']) && $_GET['modal'] == true) {
     $variables['theme_hook_suggestions'][] = 'page__modal';
   }
 }
```

**2) create a new file page--modal.tpl.php**

Copy all stuff from normal page.tpl and delete all unnecessary stuff like #header or tabs or footer

**3) every page you add ?modal=1 will now use this template**
do it with the [l() function](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!common.inc/function/l/7)

**4) Advanced stuff**

If you want to add a query to every link yourself but via a class attribute: include a little javascriptfunction in your normal page.tpl that parses all links with a class "modal" and add the modal this way

something like that

```
$(function() {
   $("a.modal").attr('href', function(i, h) {
     return h + (h.indexOf('?') != -1 ? "&modal=true" : "?modal=1");
   });
});
```

Also see [4. Adding JavaScript to your theme or module](http://drupal.org/node/304255)

Comment: Hi Steff, Thanks for the input. This is close to what I am after as you queued in on '$variables['theme_hook_suggestions'][]' which I just figured out. Problem is that a popup is only one instance where I require only the data. Guess what I need now is a way to pick out what page is trying to display so I can apply the theme_hook_suggestion. You have a way to do this? (btw. I can get the node but not page.)

Comment: After researching further I came to the conclusion that I needed to test for two scenarios. First I needed to test for node type using `code` isset($vars['node']->type))`code` in the The other was for view type `code`isset($vars['page']['#views_contextual_links_info']['views_ui']['view_display_id'])`code`. With those I was able to pick out when I needed to switch the .tpl files. Thanks for your assistance.